# Setup redis-cluster with Django

Tags: python, django, caching, redis, redis-cluster

**Problem Statement**
Use `django-redis` with redis clustering.

An error occurs when interacting with the cache.
The error points to a pickle operation on an instance of the `ConnectionPool` class where
one of it's attributes, a thread lock, cannot be serialized and results in the following error:

```
  TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.lock' object
```

**To Reproduce**
Steps to reproduce the behavior:

1. Run a redis cluster that `REDIS_URL` points to.
2. Setup `CACHES` in Django settings file.

   ```py
   CACHES = {
       "default": {
           "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
           "LOCATION": REDIS_URL,
           "OPTIONS": {
               "REDIS_CLIENT_CLASS": "redis.cluster.RedisCluster",
               "REDIS_CLIENT_KWARGS": {
                   "url": REDIS_URL,
               },
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Run the Django console and try to interact with the cache e.g. `cache.get("somekey")`

**Expected behavior**
The value of the key from the Redis cluster.

**Stack trace**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python3.9/site-packages/redis/cluster.py", line 1454, in initialize
    copy_kwargs = copy.deepcopy(kwargs)
  File "python3.9/copy.py", line 146, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "python3.9/copy.py", line 230, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "python3.9/copy.py", line 172, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
  File "python3.9/copy.py", line 270, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "python3.9/copy.py", line 146, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "python3.9/copy.py", line 230, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "python3.9/copy.py", line 161, in deepcopy
    rv = reductor(4)
TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.lock' object
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3552, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-6-48456cec0da8>", line 1, in <cell line: 1>
    from django.core.cache import cache; cache.get("bingo")
  File "python3.9/site-packages/django_redis/cache.py", line 91, in get
    value = self._get(key, default, version, client)
  File "python3.9/site-packages/django_redis/cache.py", line 31, in _decorator
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "python3.9/site-packages/django_redis/cache.py", line 98, in _get
    return self.client.get(key, default=default, version=version, client=client)
  File "python3.9/site-packages/django_redis/client/default.py", line 253, in get
    client = self.get_client(write=False)
  File "python3.9/site-packages/django_redis/client/default.py", line 105, in get_client
    self._clients[index] = self.connect(index)
  File "python3.9/site-packages/django_redis/client/default.py", line 118, in connect
    return self.connection_factory.connect(self._server[index])
  File "python3.9/site-packages/django_redis/pool.py", line 72, in connect
    connection = self.get_connection(params)
  File "python3.9/site-packages/django_redis/pool.py", line 92, in get_connection
    return self.redis_client_cls(
  File "python3.9/site-packages/redis/cluster.py", line 592, in __init__
    self.nodes_manager = NodesManager(
  File "python3.9/site-packages/redis/cluster.py", line 1286, in __init__
    self.initialize()
  File "python3.9/site-packages/redis/cluster.py", line 1490, in initialize
    raise RedisClusterException(
redis.exceptions.RedisClusterException: ERROR sending "cluster slots" command to redis server 127.0.0.1:7000. error: cannot pickle '_thread.lock' object
```

**Environment:**

- Python version: 3.9
- Django Redis Version: 5.2.0
- Django Version: 3.2.13
- Redis Version: 7.0.0
- redis-py Version: 4.3.1

Comment: Glad you asked this question because I'm looking into upgrading to a cluster and can't find any supporting documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is django_redis.pool.ConnectionFactory.get_connection
makes a pool (of class redis.connection.ConnectionPool)

```
  pool = self.get_or_create_connection_pool(params)
  return self.redis_client_cls(
      connection_pool=pool, **self.redis_client_cls_kwargs)
```

and passes it to

```
redis.cluster.RedisCluster.__init__( ... **kwargs ) (so kwargs now has connection_pool)
redis.cluster.NodesManager.__init__
redis.cluster.NodesManager.initialize()
    kwargs = self.connection_kwargs
    copy_kwargs = copy.deepcopy(kwargs)     *******
    *** die!  ConnectionPool has a _thread.lock, not pickle-able. ***
```

Because redis.connection.ConnectionPool has _thread.lock, deepcopy() fails.

Solution #1:
[6] calls RedisCluster.from_url directly from
django_redis.client.DefaultClient.connect(), bypassing
ConnectionFactory and ConnectionPool.
ConnectionPool.get_connection() makes the deadly connection_pool.

Solution #2:
Make a shim class of RedisCluster to drop "connection_pool" from
kwargs [7].

Solution #3:
Mess with RedisCluster before using it [8].
redis.cluster.RedisCluster.__ init __ scrubs kwargs before passing
it to NodesManager.

```
    kwargs = cleanup_kwargs(**kwargs)
```

It removes keys listed in redis.cluster.KWARGS_DISABLED_KEYS, which has

```
  KWARGS_DISABLED_KEYS = ("host", "port")
```

[8] adds "connection_pool" so cleanup_kwargs() removes the pesky key.

References 
[6] https://github.com/jazzband/django-redis/issues/208
see cKurultayKalkan msg 2022-10-28
django-redis + redis-py 4.0 (with cluster)
add a shim class to redis.cluster.RedisCluster

```
class CustomRedisCluster(DefaultClient):
    def connect(self, index):
        """Override the connection retrival function."""
        return RedisCluster.from_url(self._server[index])
```

in settings.py,

```
CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
        "LOCATION": REDIS_URL,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "CLIENT_CLASS": "redis_client.CustomRedisCluster",
        },
    }
}
```

[7] Add an adapter class in front of RedisCluster, to get rid of the
pesky 'connection_pool'.

```
import redis.cluster
class RedisClusterShim( redis.cluster.RedisCluster ) :
    def __init__( self,   *args, **kwargs ) :
        kwargs.pop( 'connection_pool', None )
        # redis.cluster.NodesManager.initialize() does connection_pool.deepcopy,
        # but redis.connection.ConnectionPool has a _thread.lock, not pickle-able.
        super().__init__( *args, **kwargs )
```

[8] mess with RedisCluster before using it, eg. add it to settings.py

```
def messWithRedisCluster() :
    import redis
    redis.cluster.KWARGS_DISABLED_KEYS = ("host", "port", "connection_pool" )
messWithRedisCluster()
```